# installation error in Acumatica Framework

Tags: acumatica

When I install the Acumatica Framework on Microsoft Windows 64 bit, I get the following error:

**

> *The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package.This error code
>   is 2229.*

**

Answer (score 1):

Your installation package is most likely corrupt. Try downloading it again.

Comment: Could you provide the link of installer if possible?

Comment: It is available on the partner portal. I can also give you a direct URL if you e-mail me - gmichaud at acumatica.

Comment: I can install the acumatica framework sucessfully.But ,I got the error when I run
the soultion .
"An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

By the way, could you give me for sample question for T100_Acumatica?

Comment: Something is wrong on your system - I suggest you try on a different machine if you can to see if you get same result.

Comment: I can run on another machine.So,I create the first page of the RapidByte application.I  Added the CountryMaint Graph in my application .And then I rebuild the solution.
At these time i got the following error.The type or namespace name 'PX' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
The type or namespace name 'PX' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'PXGraph' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: This is a separate training issue/question, which is outside scope of StackOverflow. Please request support through your partner or partner area manager for that.